# ListView: getting an actual item object from ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm adding items of my own class to `ListView` (the listview has bindings set up appropriately):

```
_listView.Items.Add(new ProblemsListItem());
```

I have a `MouseDoubleClick` handler which acquires a `ListViewItem` that was clicked:

```
void onProblemDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = FindVisualParent<ListViewItem, ListView>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);
}

public static TParent FindVisualParent<TParent, TLimit>(DependencyObject obj) where TParent : DependencyObject
{
    while (obj != null && !(obj is TParent))
    {
        if (obj is TLimit)
            return null;
        obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
    }
    return obj as TParent;
}
```

My qestion is: how can I convert this `ListViewItem` to my `ProblemsListItem` object, or get this object from the item?

I've tried inheriting `ProblemsListItem` from `ListViewItem`. Then I can, of course, convert `item` to `ProblemsListItem` type in the handler, but this totally breaks ListView: all columns are empty, it's not being filled properly.

Comment: a simple cast to ProblemsListItem from the SelectedItem will work.

Comment: @VasileMarianFălămaș: what's `SelectedItem`? I only have `ListViewItem` here, and it can't be cast to `ProblemsListItem`.

Comment: how about `ListViewItem.DataContext` isn't it contains `ProblemsListItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things wrong in your example which you should consider to correct in order to have wpf play nice with your custom logic.

> *I have a MouseDoubleClick handler which acquires a ListViewItem that
>   was clicked:*

If you have a custom container that inherits from ListViewItem you should conside subscribing to mouse events inside the class and so you will avoid finding the instance of container. You will be inside the instance of currently clicked container anyways.

---

> *how can I convert this ListViewItem to my ProblemsListItem object, or
>   get this object from the item?*

In order to get the item behind the container in wpf you can use the method ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-De/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.itemfromcontainer.aspx

---

> *I've tried inheriting ProblemsListItem from ListViewItem. Then I can, of course, convert item to ProblemsListItem type in the handler, but
>   this totally breaks ListView: all columns are empty, it's not being
>   filled properly.*

You should then also override ListView and make it use your custom container for displaying items.

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
        protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
        {
            return new ProblemsListItem();
        }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that explains. WPF seems (over)complicated to a novice, and documentation is either lacking or hard to find. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ItemContainerGenerator` to get data item:

```
var dataItem = yourListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(yourListViewItem);
```

but this code smells. I can't see any reasons to not to use data binding, and handle double click as executing of `ICommand` implementation.

Comment: I don't even understand what you said there, only been using WPF for a couple of days. This is utility code, my goal is to write it with the least effort and the least number of lines. Also, in the most clear and readable fashion so that other people who don't know WPF can understand it. So far it looks readable to me.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case if someone needs easy solution to this problem, here is a way to get your actual item from ListViewItem.

```
void onProblemDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
 var item = sender as ListViewItem;
            if (item != null && item.IsSelected)                                         
            {
               //here is your ProblemsListItem item           
               var actualItem = (ProblemsListItem)item.Content;               
            }
}
```